# Issue with Flutter Navigation: Back Button Behavior after context.push()

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-go-router

Problem Description:

I'm building a Flutter application where I have a bottom navigation bar with several tabs. In one of these tabs, I'm using context.push('/createPost') to navigate to a new page where users can create posts. However, after navigating back from the /createPost page using the system's back button, I noticed that the bottom navigation bar's current index is unexpectedly reset to 0 while showing the correct page of the _previousIndex, regardless of which tab I was on before navigating to /createPost.

ScaffoldWithNavBar

```
class ScaffoldWithNavBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final String location;
  const ScaffoldWithNavBar(
      {super.key, required this.child, required this.location});

  final Widget child;

  @override
  State<ScaffoldWithNavBar> createState() => _ScaffoldWithNavBarState();
}

class _ScaffoldWithNavBarState extends State<ScaffoldWithNavBar> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  int _previousIndex = 0;

  static const List<MyCustomBottomNavBarItem> tabs = [
    MyCustomBottomNavBarItem(
      initialLocation: '/home',
      label: 'Home',
      icon: Icon(Clarity.home_line),
      activeIcon: Icon(Clarity.home_line),
    ),
    MyCustomBottomNavBarItem(
      initialLocation: '/map',
      label: 'Map',
      icon: Icon(Clarity.map_line),
      activeIcon: Icon(Clarity.map_line),
    ),
    MyCustomBottomNavBarItem(
      initialLocation: '/createPost',
      label: 'Create Post',
      icon: Icon(Clarity.plus_circle_line),
      activeIcon: Icon(Clarity.plus_circle_line),
    ),
    MyCustomBottomNavBarItem(
      initialLocation: '/discover',
      label: 'Discover',
      icon: Icon(Clarity.search_line),
      activeIcon: Icon(Clarity.search_line),
    ),
    MyCustomBottomNavBarItem(
      initialLocation: '/profile',
      label: 'Profile',
      icon: Icon(Clarity.user_line),
      activeIcon: Icon(Clarity.user_line),
    )
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: widget.child,
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        selectedItemColor: BlndColors.red,
        unselectedItemColor: BlndColors.brown,
        showSelectedLabels: false,
        showUnselectedLabels: false,
        iconSize: 30.0,
        type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
        onTap: (int index) {
          _goOtherTab(context, index);
        },
        currentIndex: widget.location == '/home'
            ? 0
            : widget.location == '/map'
                ? 1
                : widget.location == '/discover'
                    ? 3
                    : widget.location == '/profile'
                        ? 4
                        : 2,
        items: tabs,
      ),
    );
  }
```

Method _goOtherTab

```
void _goOtherTab(BuildContext context, int index) {
    if (index == _currentIndex) return;
    GoRouter router = GoRouter.of(context);
    String location = tabs[index].initialLocation;

    if (index != 2) {
      _previousIndex = _currentIndex;
      print('previous index: $_previousIndex');
    }

    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });

    if (index == 2) {
      context.push('/createPost').then((value) {
        _currentIndex = _previousIndex;
        print('current index after push: $_currentIndex');
      });
    } else {
      print('current index: $_currentIndex');
      router.go(location);
    }
  }
}
```

Router Config

```
final _rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
final _shellNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
  initialLocation: '/',
  navigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
  routes: [
    ShellRoute(
      navigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
      pageBuilder: (context, state, child) {
        return NoTransitionPage(
          child: ScaffoldWithNavBar(
            location: state.matchedLocation,
            child: child,
          ),
        );
      },
      routes: [
        GoRoute(
          name: 'home',
          path: '/home',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const HomePage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'map',
          path: '/map',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const MapPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'discover',
          path: '/discover',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const DiscoverPage(),
        ),
        GoRoute(
          name: 'profile',
          path: '/profile',
          parentNavigatorKey: _shellNavigatorKey,
          builder: (context, state) => const ProfilePage(),
        ),
      ],
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'builder',
      path: '/',
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state) => const BuilderWidget(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'signIn',
      path: '/signIn',
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state) => const SignInPage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'signUp',
      path: '/signUp',
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state) => const SignUpPage(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      name: 'createPost',
      path: '/createPost',
      parentNavigatorKey: _rootNavigatorKey,
      builder: (context, state) => const CreatePostPage(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

What I've Tried:

I've implemented a solution where I store the previous index before navigating to /createPost and then set it back after navigating back. However, this approach doesn't seem to work as expected.

I've also reviewed the documentation for the routing package (go_router) I'm using, but I couldn't find any specific details related to this issue.

Answer (score 0):

*GoRouter* uses **declarative routing** (introduced as Flutter Navigator 2.0) which is an approach where developers define the routes available within the application along with their associated destinations in an hierarchical structure, where routes are mapped to specific screens (widgets). Developers describe navigation by triggering actions which "go" to a destination. **Navigating to a destination using declarative routing will replace the current stack of "screens" with the stack of "screens" configured to be displayed for the destination route**. Upon navigation, GoRouter constructs the stack of routes based on the routing configuration and the requested route.

In contrast, with **imperative navigation** where navigation consists of directly pushing or popping routes onto the navigation stack.

In you code you are mixing declarative routing with imperative routing (you are using "push" to navigate to the '/createPost'), which is fine as long as you are [aware of it](https://pub.dev/documentation/go_router/latest/topics/Navigation-topic.html). In addition, since declarative routing rebuilds the stack of screens when navigating using "go", it is not possible to keep track of the navigation history between routes without using some state-management techniques. This would be very tricky and not at straight answer beacause YOU shall defined how the history is tracked (Would you want to track only when navigating between shelled routes or to any route? Track both "go" and "push"? What happens when using "pop"? What happens when pressing the back button? ...)

Instead of keeping track of the current index with a variable and using [local ephemeral state](https://docs.flutter.dev/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/ephemeral-vs-app) (which could be easily reset), you could in your `ScaffoldWithNavBar` get the index based on your current location:

One possible way is using an enum:

```dart
enum MainShelledPageRoutes {
  home,
  map,
  discover,
  profile,
}

/// Extension on [MainShelledPageRoutes] enum to provide utility methods.
extension MainShelledPageRoutesExt on MainShelledPageRoutes {
  /// The name of this [GoRoute] as defined in [PageRoutes].
  String get name {
    switch (this) {
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.home:
        return "home";
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.map:
        return "map";
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.discover:
        return "discover";
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.profile:
        return "profile";
    }
  }

  /// Returns the path of this route.
  String get path {
    switch (this) {
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.home:
        return "/home";
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.map:
        return "/map";
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.discover:
        return "/discover";
      case MainShelledPageRoutes.profile:
        return "/profile";
    }
  }

  /// Retrieves the index corresponding to the provided path.
  ///
  /// Returns -1 if the provided path is not part of the shelled routes.
  static int getIndex(final String path) {
    return MainShelledPageRoutes.values.indexWhere((v) => v.path == path);
  }
}
```

And then in `ScaffoldWithNavBar` just call `MainShelledPageRoutesExt.getIndex(location)` to get the current index.